# Pandas - Changing date format from yyyy-dd-mm to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: pandas

I am trying to convert the timestamp `2018-06-11T00:00:00.000000000` to `2018-11-06T00:00:00.000000000`

I have tried `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` but it dint help

Have also tried `pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime("%Y-%d-%m")`

Comment: How did you create the initial timestamp, why not just fix it when creating that one by specifying the proper format?

Comment: Provide a reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

You can use format:

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series(['2018-06-11T00:00:00.000000000'])

In [12]: pd.to_datetime(s, format='%Y-%d-%mT%H:%M:%S')
Out[12]:
0   2018-11-06
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

i.e.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%d-%mT%H:%M:%S')
```